# Does Ubuntu 12.04 32-Bit detect more than 4GB of RAM?

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Ubuntu Desktop 32Bit Support more than 4GB Memory with default installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20049/does-ubuntu-desktop-32bit-support-more-than-4gb-memory-with-default-installation)

I am having some issues with 64-bit and while I find it very good I will move back to 32-bit for at least a month until all the minor 64-bit issues in 12.04 are dealt with.

My only question right now is whether 32-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 detects/supports more than 4 GB of RAM.